# Can't start AZURE VM anymore: StorageAccountOperationInternalError

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

VM usually starts automatically every morning. Today this error occured, so there is no way to start VM and connect via RDP:

Provisioning failed. Internal error occurred while accessing storage account protrailer7669.. StorageAccountOperationInternalError

It's Windows Server 2012 R2

I have upgraded my VM Size to the next higher one (A3->A4) and downgraded it again (A4->A3) and I can start and connect to VM again.

Answer (score 0):

We managed to sort out our non-booting VM. It seems for some reason a data disk had been added to the VM and both the OS and Data entries on the VM pointed to the same VHD so the blob VHD was saying it was in use. I detached the data disk, which said it failed, but still removed the data disk entry. Once this was done the VM could boot.